# How write NULL in a query on Excel?

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, null

I'm writing queries on excel so I can paste them into MySQL later. 
Let's say I have the following in one of my columns.

=IF(ISBLANK(R3), "", "SELECT ID FROM EMS_R_DATA WHERE LABEL = '"&R3&"';")

Instead I want this

=IF(ISBLANK(R3), NULL, "SELECT ID FROM EMS_R_DATA WHERE LABEL = '"&R3&"';")

I use the above script in another column to do my insert -
insert into tableName (colName) values(Column_with_value_above)

Unfortunately Excel doesn't recognize NULL, is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just going to copy the paste later on, just do this:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(R3), "NULL", "SELECT ID FROM EMS_R_DATA WHERE LABEL = '"&R3&"';")
```

It'll create the string "NULL", which when you see in Excel won't have the quotes which and you paste to your database software will just become NULL without the quotes.

Comment: Thank you sir. I feel dumb for not figuring this out. This works as expected